# 'invalid label' error when returning JSON form rails controller when Firebug is closed

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, firebug

If I have Firebug console open, and return the following in a rails controller in response to an ajax call:

```
format.json { render :json => Appointment.find_by_id(1) }
```

I get an 'invalid label' error. But it works fine it Firebug is closed.

Any ideas???

Comment: You return exactly that string?  I bet it does not "work fine" when Firebug is closed.

Comment: Actually it does. Why wouldn't it?

Comment: I have this same problem, except it doesn't work with Firebug closed or open. Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 1):

What solved it for me was:

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({
          jsonp: null,
          jsonpCallback: null
        });
```

The problem is that the browser treats the json as jsonp and adds a callback to it.

This command solves it (at least for me).

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be related to using JQuery 1.5.  Could you confirm that this doesn't happen with JQuery 1.4.4?

Answer (score 0):

I concur with Tomer that this is a json-vs-jsonp problem, but his code didn't fix it for me. I fixed it by adding this jQuery code (works in 1.4 and 1.6):

```
$(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({
    dataType: 'json'
  });
});
```